# SQL Linq join List VB NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, join

`Tabella_Pratiche` is entities of my db, `P_ListLettore` is a list of object.
When I try join `Tabella_Pratiche` and `P_ListLettore` I produce exception.

```
Dim listPraticheEsistenti As List(Of Tabella_Pratiche)

listPraticheEsistenti = (From c In DB.Tabella_Pratiche Join b In P_ListLettore On c.posizione Equals b.AssignamentID And                c.data_affido.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") Equals b.R_RecordPA.Data_inizio_affidamento.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") Where c.tipo_mandato = "SPG" Select c).ToList
```

> exception " Eccezione non gestita di tipo
>   'System.NotSupportedException' in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> Ulteriori informazioni: Impossibile creare un valore costante di tipo
>   'ImportPratiche.RecordPrSPG'. In questo contesto sono supportati solo
>   tipi primitivi o enumerazione. "

Comment: In the future please supply English exception messages. Alternatively there is a [Spanish SO](http://es.stackoverflow.com/) as well if you prefer to communicate in Spanish (I realize this is Italian but these are the only SO I  knowof).  The error is because you cannot use the join syntax between an in memory list and a list that would be accessed using Linq to Sql (still on database). If you want a close equivalent you could use `Contains` which is supported and will be translated into a `IN` clause on the database but this only supports lists of simple types like a list of `int` or `string`.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Also you cant use ToString(""), that is a .net concept and will not translate to sql. It could be that is what the problem is. I do not read Italian so I am guessing here, there might also be other issues in your code.

Comment: I had tried without tostring but I had the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Like @Igor wrote in his comment, you cannot join an in-memory list of objects with a database result.
This is due to Entity Framework tries to convert the LINQ into a SQL statement and  `P_ListLettore` is unknown in your database thus unknown to Entity Framework.

What you can do is to load data from the database first and "join" in-memory afterwards (the following code is completely untested):

```
    'IEnumerable with AssignamentIDs'
    Dim assignmentIDs = From p In P_ListLettore
                        Select p.AssignamentID

    'Load Tabella_Pratiche with matching IDs from DB and convert into in-memory List'
    Dim tmpPratiche = (From c In DB.Tabella_Pratiche
                       Where c.tipo_mandato = "SPG" And assignmentIDs.Contains(c.posizione)
                       Select c).ToList()

    ' Perform Join on both in-memory lists with ID and Date'
    Dim listPraticheEsistenti = (From c In tmpPratiche
                                 Join b In P_ListLettore On c.posizione Equals b.AssignamentID 
                                      And c.data_affido Equals b.R_RecordPA.Data_inizio_affidamento
                                  Select c).ToList
```

Be aware that you can only use a small set of .NET functions in a Linq2Sql query, `Date.ToString(format)` will not work for example.

Comment: There is a problem Error  Can not convert the value of type '<anonymous type> (line 130)' in '<anonymous type>

Comment: I would not want to load P_LISTALETTORE in database

Comment: You don´t have to load P_LISTALETTORE. You have to load all `Tabella_Pratiche`, loop over `P_LISTALETTORE` and check if `posizione` and `data_affido` are equals to `AssignamentID` and `Data_inizio_affidamento`. This will be slower but should work.  will edit my answer on monday when I´m back in office

Comment: btw...sorry that I posted an incorrect answer. Usually I test my code before posting...